# Javascript generic isBlank function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a generic isBlank function in JS like Java StringUtils.isBlank();
I would like your opinion on the implementation in case I missed something like == vs === or better implementation?
so the following are considerd blank:

```
var a;         //undefined => true
var b = null;  //null            => true
var c = '';    //emptyString     => true
var d = '  ';   //emptyString    => true
var e = ' \b \f \n \r \t \v \0 ';   //emptyString with other white space => true
```

Implementation:

```
    function isBlank(value){      
        return(value == undefined || value == null || value.trim() == '');
    }
```

```js
var a;         //undefined => true
var b = null;  //null    => true
var c = '';    //emptyString  => true
var d = '  ';   //emptyString  => true
var d1 = ' \b \f \n \r \t \v \0 ';
var e = 'X';    //char  => false
var f = '#';   //char  => false
var g = '1';   //digit  => false



  function isBlank(value){      
   return(value == undefined || value == null || value.trim() == '');
  }

console.log('a => ' + isBlank(a));
console.log('b => ' + isBlank(b));
console.log('c => ' + isBlank(c));
console.log('d => ' + isBlank(d));
console.log('d1 => ' + isBlank(d1));
console.log('e => ' + isBlank(e));
console.log('f => ' + isBlank(f));
console.log('g => ' + isBlank(g));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shorten your function by using `!` operator which will convert both `undefined` and `null` to true (since it negates falsy values):

```js
var a;         //undefined => true
var b = null;  //null    => true
var c = '';    //emptyString  => true
var d = '  ';   //emptyString  => true
var e = 'X';    //char  => false
var f = '#';   //char  => false
var g = '1';   //digit  => false
var h = 1;   //digit  => false
var d1 = ' \b \f \n \r \t \v \0 '; // whitespaces => true
var d2 = ' \b \f \n aa \r \t \v \0 '; // whitespaces with regular text => false

function isBlank(value){      
   return !value || !value.toString().trim() || /^[\s\b\0]+$/.test(value.toString());
}

console.log('a => ' + isBlank(a));
console.log('b => ' + isBlank(b));
console.log('c => ' + isBlank(c));
console.log('d => ' + isBlank(d));
console.log('e => ' + isBlank(e));
console.log('f => ' + isBlank(f));
console.log('g => ' + isBlank(g));
console.log('h => ' + isBlank(h));
console.log('h => ' + isBlank(d1));
console.log('h => ' + isBlank(d2));
```

EDIT: added `isBlank2` to support numbers if needed

Comment: `!value.trim()` will throw an error if a number is passed.

Comment: @gforce301 that's true, not sure if numbers are taken into consideration but added `isBlank2` to make it more flexible. thanks !

Comment: @mickl  I forgot about white-space character \b \f \n \r \t \v \0 can you see revised question (added d1) ? thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @user648026 I would try with regex like in modified answer